# Everyone for non livings

Tags: usage

Can everyone be used for non living objects as in the following sentence

> Everyone of the films you suggested are not worth seeing.

It looks weird but I found it in a book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You could say:

> Every one of those films.

As two separate words "every one" can refer to inanimate objects that are part of a group.

However, "everyone" is reserved as a pronoun for people. It is interchangeable with the word "everybody".

Comment: In *speech*, they're just as distinct as they are in the (correct) written forms. ***Everyone** will be given an apple, and **every one** will be ripe*. The first has primary stress on the initial syllable of the "triplet", the second (two-word) one has primary stress on the ***final*** syllable.

Comment: ...actually, the space *can* represent a pause. I can imagine heavy stress on the initial syllable for both in, say, highly emphatic ***Everyone** get out! And I mean **every one**!* But in that case there would *definitely* be a noticeable pause before the final ***one***.

Comment: Note that even with the edit the diction used here is unusual.  "Every film you suggested", "Each of the films you suggested", and "All of the films you suggested" would all be more natural constructions.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer and "None of the films you suggested are worth seeing", which moves the negation up front, is more natural still IMO. But the "every one" construct is still reasonable in general.